# generating a box of stars surrounding text with for loops in c++

Tags: c++, for-loop

I'm trying to make a program in c++ which surrounds some given lines of code with a box of stars in which the sentences fit 'neatly'. I've done this for a small text which consists of only the same sentence and it works. But when trying to make this program work for texts with more than only one sentence it fails because the sentences aren't all the same size. How can I fix this issue? Here's my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
int r, c;

for( r = 0; r < 5; ++r )
{
    for( c = 0; c < 28; ++c )
    {
        if( r == 0 || r == 4 )
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        else
        {
            if( c == 0 || c == 27 )
                cout << "*";
            if(r >= 1 && c == 1){
                cout << " this is a test sentence";
            }
                if(c > 1 && c < 4){
                    cout << " ";
                }
        }
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain all those magic numbers? This is quite annoying anti-pattern.

Comment: You need to calculate the length of each sentence and pad with spaces to fill the box.

Comment: as said, I want the text to fit "neatly" in the box of stars, so I basically want that my longest sentence (in this case I've tried it out with only one sentence) to be surrounded by the outermost stars of the box, by trial and error i've found that my box withthis sentence should consist out of 27 columns. 5 is the amount of rows uot of which my box will consist, because there will be three sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might change your code, so that it uses variables, not literal constants. After you do that, you have two options based on how you want to calculate the width of the box:

- fixed - use `cout << std::setw(fixed_width) << std::left << sentences[i];` (in a loop)
- variable - use loop or `std::max_element` to determine the longest sentence and do the same thing as with fixed width

where you'll use `std::vector<std::string> sentences`.

I'll also add how neat can be what you currently have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    const int width = 20;
    const char c = '*';

    std::string horizontal_line(width, c);
    std::string horizontal_line_empty(c + std::string(width - 2, c) + c);

    cout << horizontal_line << endl << horizontal_line_empty << endl;
    cout << c << std::setw(width - 2) << std::left << std::string("hello") << c << endl;
    cout << horizontal_line_empty << endl << horizontal_line << endl;
}
```

I hope you'll get something from it.